# populate thetextbox based on drodpwn selection, value is coming from list

Tags: databind

I have a sharepoint list employee with column first and second.
First has a value ( A,B,C,D) and second has value (1,2,3,4) respectively.
first = drodpwn
second = textbox
i need that when i select "A" in dropdown then "1" should get populated in second field. values should be coming from list fields.
Please help with c#. Thanks

This is not exact cascading, i have one dropdown and next is textbox. I want c# code like method "ontextselected"

Comment: Is this Custom form? or list default NewForm.aspx?

Comment: yes this is custom form, i want something method like ontextselect